# repeated set of lines

Tags: text-processing

A set of 3 lines in my .txt file

many sets are one after the other.

For example:

```
1.message: afcdd77f17519b364c1992095399d
2.signature: bbfecd2f9f1c2fabedb3d15f310
3.-----------
1.message: 3184f8993f23b86b1ab9ccb322c470
2.signature: 4a216984322d840baaeee5c8c4d0a0
3.-----------
```

I want to make separate "message" -'new'.txt file (one after one)

separate "signature" -'new'.txt file (one after one)

Is there any command for this?

Comment: You want all message: afcdd77f17519b364c1992095399d in one file and signature: bbfecd2f9f1c2fabedb3d15f310 in another? or should the the line make up the filename, e.g., message-afcdd77f17519b364c1992095399d.txt

Comment: So...you previously asked this question which got closed but then you ask again in exactly the same way?  Maybe you should see why it was closed before first?

Comment: bac0n yes ..i need 2 separate files one is containing message, another one containingg signature ..

Comment: `sed -n -e '1~3w message-new.txt' -e '2~3w signature-new.txt' file` or just the numbers

Comment: Ray sorry for English, I am a learner

Comment: bac0n Thank you so much it is worked .....
Thank you, Thank you,Thank you.....

Comment: like a counter?

Comment: bac0n i want to add numbers (01) in last --- for all messages afcdd77f17519b364c1992095399d how to add???/

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ': ' 'NR % 3 == 1 || NR % 3 == 2 {printf("%s: %s%s\n", $1, $2, ($1 == "message") ? "01":"") > $1"-new.txt"}' file
```

Or

```
sed -n -e 's/message.*/&01/w message-new.txt' -e '/signature.*/w signature-new.txt' file
```